# 3en1compteur V3: PHP hit counter

Tags: php

3en1Compteur is a hit counter written in PHP
http://www.petit-kiwi.com/3en1compteur-compteur-visites-php

we have a website that offers three language
"English, French, Spanish"
with this code here, it makes machine translation.
how: integre this code here on

```
 <?php echo $language['Aujourd\'hui']; ?>

<?php echo $language['Total']; ?>
```

sure

```
<?php include_once('/home/demo/public_html/dev/counter.php');echo "Total : $c_alltime ";echo "Aujourd'hui : $c_today";echo "En ligne : $c_online";?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here:

Where is your `counter.php` file located? In this case `/counter.php` means that the file is located in your [root directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory). Make sure you know which directory that `counter.php` is in, and include that path appropriately.

Another major thing to note here, assuming that $language is an array variable which is initialized and located in your `counter.php` file, there are two ways to access it in a string:

1. [Concatenate it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). 
   Example: `echo "The language is: " . $language['Aujourd'];`
2. Parse it directly within the string, which you can read about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). Example: `echo "The language is: {$language['Aujourd']}";`

So try reading up on these basics and give it another shot, and see if you can come back with some more specific questions!

Comment: Hello,

3en1Compteur is a hit counter written in PHP
http://www.petit-kiwi.com/3en1compteur-compteur-visites-php

we have a website that offers three language
"English, French, Spanish"
with this code here, it makes machine translation.
how: integre this code here on

   

     <?php echo $language['Aujourd\'hui']; ?>

    <?php echo $language['Total']; ?>

sure

    <?php include_once('/home/demo/public_html/dev/counter.php');echo "Total : $c_alltime ";echo "Aujourd'hui : $c_today";echo "En ligne : $c_online";?>

thank you

Answer (score 0):

500 error

```
<?php include_once('/counter.php'); echo  "  {$language['Aujourd']}"; ($c_alltime) - {$language['Total']}"; ($c_today) "; ?>
```

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{'

le script de php compteur 3 en 1

the two code here replaced
three language  for different countries

`Aujourd'hui :  ($c_today)` Total visiteurs :  ($c_alltime)`

`<?php echo $language['Aujourd']; ?>`

`<?php echo $language['Total']; ?>`

`<?php include_once('/home/demo/public_html/dev/counter.php');echo "Total visiteurs :  ($c_alltime) - Aujourd'hui :  ($c_today)";?></a>`

thank you

Comment: Hello,
we have a website that offers three language
"English, French, Spanish"
with this code here, it makes machine translation.
how: integre this code here on

 
echo $language['Aujourd\'hui']; 
echo $language['Total']; 

sure

    <?php include_once('/home/demo/public_html/dev/counter.php');echo "Total : $c_alltime ";echo "Aujourd'hui : $c_today";echo "En ligne : $c_online";?>

thank you